# error: use of undeclared identifier 'tail'

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am writing this code for insertion at the tail of a linked list. When I call the function in the main block there is an error in the tail parameter. Can someone tell why?
I made a function for insertion at head, but it works absolutely fine.

code -

````
class Node {
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    //constructor type 1
    Node(int data) {
        this -> data = data;
        this -> next = NULL;
    }
};
 
void insertAtTail(Node* &tail, int data) {
    //New node create
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    tail -> next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

int main() {

 insertAtTail(tail, 20);
    print(tail);
}```
````

Comment: You didn't define `tail` in `main`. Also, you'd need a reference to the *first* node, or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it in code? That would be a lot if help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all: *"undeclared identifier 'tail'"*

Your `main` function suddenly references `tail` without first telling what `tail` is. It makes no sense to insert a node if you don't have anything to insert it *into*.

You would also need a `head` variable to have a reference to the *first* node in the list.

When you call your `print` method, you'd better pass the `head` of the list. If you pass `tail`, then `print` will only print the tail node of the list, and it seems likely you want `print` to print the whole list.

Finally, you need to take care of the case where your list is empty (`nullptr`) and where you call `insertAtTail` to insert the very *first* node of the list. In that case `tail` will be `nullptr` and it would be wrong to access `tail->next` in that situation. Moreover, you would need to also set the *head* of the list. So I'd suggest that `insertAtTail` takes a parameter for the `head` too. That way it can set the `head` to the new node in case it is the very first node of the list.

Code:

```cpp
void insertAtTail(Node* &head, Node* &tail, int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    if (head == nullptr) { // If this is the first node of the list
        head = temp;
    } else { // Only when there is already a tail node
        tail -> next = temp;
    }
    tail = temp;
}

void print(Node* head) {
    while (head != nullptr) {
        std::cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Node* head = nullptr; // A list has a head
    Node* tail = head; // ...and a tail.
    insertAtTail(head, tail, 10); // Also pass the head
    insertAtTail(head, tail, 20);
    insertAtTail(head, tail, 30);
    print(head);  // Print the whole list, not just the tail
}
```